# Zipfile namelist() missing members from archive

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-zipfile

I'm currently trying to open an .xlsx file with zipfile on Python, finding all files with `namelist()`, then using `.count()` to find all images in .png format within the archive.

My problem is currently, the list returned by `namelist()` function returns only 1680 elements.

After saving the xlsx file as an html, I am able to view all images contained in the excel spreadsheet and the total file count is 3,352 files.

I checked documentation for zipfile and exhausted the best Google searches I could muster. I appreciate any hints or advice!

Here's the snippet of code I'm using:

```
import zipfile as zf

xlsx = 'myfile.xlsx'
xlsx_file = zf.ZipFile(xlsx)
fileList = xlsx_file.namelist()
```

Comment: A `.xlsx` file is not a `.zip` format archive, so `ZipFile` won't work with one. Save the Excel file as `.csv` file and use the `csv` module to read it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, @martineau.

I understand that `.xlsx` is not explicitly a `.zip` format archive, but I've been successful in handling an `.xlsx` file using the ZipFile module. 

Previously you noted that I should've uploaded a file for others to reproduce the issue, I've made it temporarily available for download using this [link](https://ufile.io/ytg5z):

Comment: Are you sure there aren't duplicate images in the file?  I assume that the archive would contain only a single instance of any image, no matter how many times it's used in the document.

Comment: @jasonharper thank you for your reply. I did take a closer look at what files were present after saving the html file and it does appear that image files are duplicate in the media folder.

Comment: So after further investigation; The excel file contains 1721 images in total (this is after selecting all objects, and running a VBA script that copies all alt texts of images to the cell next to its appropriate object.)

Upon opening the same xlsx filewith 7Zip, the xl/media folder only contains 1667 images. Any idea why this would be?

Answer (score 0):

maybe convert it to a wheel file? wheel works good to me